# How to read real-time data from a webpage using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where I placed a counter so I want an output page where those results from the counter will be displayed in real-time on a separate output web page.

I have tried using JQUERY `$.get` but its simply giving me the web page html code instead of the counting results in real-time.

```
function update() {
  $.get("server.php", {}, function(results) {
    var color1 = $(results).find("#color_type_div").html();    
    var color2 = $(results).find('#color_type_divv').html();      
    $('#demo1').html(color1);      
    $('#demo2').html(color2);
  });    
}
```

That's my code so far. I'm curious to know a way to get the real-time update of a web page.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot get real-time information from another web page in the manner you're attempting. To get real-time data you need to communicate directly with a server. The most applicable solutions for this would be Web Sockets or Server Sent Events.

Comment: Is there any example you can refer me to?